# Vector become weird when I shrink it down, please help!! (illustrator cs6)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

so i created this mosque vector
[image]

when i shrink it down the pillar bellow become stick to each other
[image]

anybody know the solution of this?
thanks

Comment: Not only the pillars.... the minarets are distorted too.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch off "Align to Pixel Grid" for all objects in the transform panel. Otherwise scaled shapes will stick to the next full pixel border.

[image]

Comment: already doing that still same result, any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you check each single element? Also inside of groups? Not likely and without having tried it: it could be on document level. Create a new document and make sure "Align new objects to grid" is off, units are not pixel and paste the drawing over.